# Gitlab: webhook event on create branch

Tags: git, gitlab, webhooks

Is it possible to run a webhook when a branch is created?

If this is not possible then does a hook fire in git when a branch is created either via git branch or git checkout -b or any other way.

Regards
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use Gitlab's [push hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#push-events) and check if the commit-id of `before` is `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: Looking at the request body, I can see "before" in the push hook, but I can't see the name of the newly created branch. 
There is the project default_branch but that is not what I need. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, having tested it, I can see it is under the "ref" setting.